# Transfer logins between two replicas in Always on

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to transfer logins between two replicas in Always on availability group automatically?

I am using SQL Server 2017 cu22.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dbatools` in `PowerShell` to sync logins between AG.

Please check for more details: https://dbatools.io/keeping-availability-group-logins-in-sync-automatically

Besides, you can [install dbatools](https://dbatools.io/download/) from the powershell gallery using `Install-Module dbatools`.

Comment: SO answers should be stand alone with links only used for reference.